# Elevation situation in kivyMD

Tags: python, kivymd

Very new in kivyMD and ran into problems from the git'go.
I'm following an example from John Elder's YouTube [channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-Rp41BzGxg&list=PLCC34OHNcOtpz7PJQ7Tv7hqFBP_xDDjqg&index=44) on creating a simple card in kivyMD (my very 1st experience in kivyMD) and there is no visible elevation plus there is a **warning**:

```
[WARNING] [KivyMD      ] If you see this error, this means that either youre using `CommonElevationBehavio`r directly
or your 'shader' dont have a `_draw_shadow` instruction, remember to overwrite this functionto draw over the image context.
Тhe figure you would like. Or your class BaseShadowMDCard is not inherited from any of the classes
('CommonElevationBehavior', 'RectangularElevationBehavior', 'CircularElevationBehavior', 'RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior', 'ObservableShadow', 'FakeRectangularElevationBehavior', 'FakeCircularElevationBehavior')
```

At first I thought, well, its probably my video card or I forgot to load something.... but I followed the video to the letter. Then I loaded the 'kitchen sink' and the elevations look beautiful.

Can someone please explain and/or tell me how can i make my elevations beautiful too?
Thank you.

PyCharm 2021.3.1 (Community Edition), Win10, kivyMD 1.0.0.dev0,

Comment: Try changing the `elevation` value.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution. Added `from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RectangularElevationBehavior`. And then modified the class to : `class BaseShadowMDCard(MDCard, RectangularElevationBehavior):`. This improves greatly the look of the card and now it looks elevated. Thank you ApuCoder for your input.